# How to refresh the nestedSortable when i add new item

Tags: jquery, nested-sortable

Hellow guys. I`m used this plugin https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable.

I'M clone item, add to list, but i cant move new item. How to refresh plugin or smth. I need to move all lists. Its my code.

```
var ns = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable ({

    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    maxLevels: 3,
    isTree: true,
    expandOnHover: 700,
    startCollapsed: false,

    change: function(){
        console.log('Relocated item');
    }
});


$("#add-next-block").clone()
            .removeAttr('id')
            .attr('id', 'group-' +id)
            .appendTo('#group-in-category-' + id);

ns.nestedSortable('refresh');



<ol class="sortable">
<li><div>Some content</div></li>
<li>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <ol>
        <li><div>Some sub-item content</div></li>
        <li><div>Some sub-item content</div></li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li><div>THIS IS CREATED BLOCK, BUT I CAN`T MOVE IT</div></li>
```

Comment: Do you resolve this problem?

Comment: any solution for this problem?